# How to formulate summation in z3py

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am very new to z3py.
I am trying to code the following 2 expressions in z3py
[image]

***and***

[image]

More information on the problem can be found  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335452/z3py-smt-coding-following-variables-and-the-formulas/30355944#30355944)

I did search stackoverflow a lot and came across a  [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362711/how-can-i-solve-minimizing-constraint-in-z3)

But unfortunately I could not get a satisfactory enough answer.

I tried coding the first one in SMT, in following way:

```
#InputGroup, BlockGroup, OutputGroup contain some integer values to represent blocks
InputGroup = [0,1,2]
BlockGroup = [2,3,4,5,6]
OutputGroup = [7,8,9]
Groups = [InputGroup, BlockGroup, OutputGroup]

NumberOfTasks = len(InputGroup)+ len(BlockGroup)+ len(OutputGroup)
M = Function('M', Intsort(), Intsort())
Task = Function('Task', Intsort(), Intsort(), Intsort())
summation1 = Int('summation1')

# each group from the Groups is represented by its index number
for r, g in enumerate(Groups): 
    for m in range(0, NumberOfTasks):
        if(m in g):
            s.add(summation1 == summation1+ M(Task(r,m)))
```

and the second expression in SMT the following way:

```
NumberOfInputs = len(InputGroup)
NumberOfBlocks = len(BlockGroup)
NumberOfOutputs = len(OutputGroup)
Node = Function('Node', Intsort(), Intsort(), Intsort())
f = Function('f', Intsort(), Intsort(), Intsort())

for r, g in enumerate(Groups):
    if(r != Groups.index(InputGroup) and r != Groups.index(OutputGroup)):
        for i in range(0,(NumberOfInputs+NumberOfBlocks+NumberOfOutputs)):
            summation2 = Int('summation2')
            for m in range(0, (NumberOfTasks)):
                if(m in g and i in g):
                    s.add(summation2 == summation2+ f(Node(r,i), Task(r,m)))
            s.add(summation2 == 1)
```

Although I get satisfactory result from the above equations, the model I get from it is kind of questionable.
I just want to know if I am representing this correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change:

```
# each group from the Groups is represented by its index number
for r, g in enumerate(Groups): 
    for m in range(0, NumberOfTasks):
        if(m in g):
           s.add(summation1 == summation1+ M(Task(r,m)))
```

to something like this:

```
# each group from the Groups is represented by its index number
sumTerms = [M(Task(r,m)) 
                  for r, g in enumerate(Groups): 
                     for m in range(0, NumberOfTasks):
                          if(m in g)]
s.add(summation1 == Sum(sumTerms))
```

and similarly for the second example.